# challenges Creating GCP BIlling with code OR-CBAT-15

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

I experience challenges setting up GCP Billing Account with an code OR-CBAT-15. i registered Amazon aws with the same billing info and it worked

Comment: Contact your credit card and ask them why they declined the transaction.

Comment: hey hi, u got this solved

Comment: same problem :(

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a customer support question, and not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

After looking for 3 months over the internet, I found that there are only 2 solutions:

1. If you have another account with an active billing account you can contact the support to resolve the issue on another account that doesn't have an active billing.
2. Buy a brand new ready account.